# JS working in codepen but not in context of my full HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still super new to coding so don't judge my code to harshly but any advice is appreciated!

I'm trying to build a budget tracker app using electron. I have a list of transactions (table) where I would like to let the user add, edit and save rows. I got it (more or less) working in codepen, but in the context of my full html file nothing happens and I cant figure out why.

I linked the js file (called table.js) before the closing body tag.

I've tried wrapping my JS in

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
// your code goes here
});
```

Which sadly didn't work. Anyways, here's the code:

Table HTML (this + the JS works in codepen):

```
<div class="five">
     <h1>Transactions</h1>
     <div class="txlist"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="1500" >
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div class="scroll" style="width:320px; height:80px; overflow:auto;">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" border="0" width="1500" id="data_table">
           <tr id="addtx">
             <td><input type="date" id="new_date" placeholder="Date"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_account" placeholder="Account"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_category" placeholder="Category"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
             <td><input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="add_row();">
             <!--<input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('')"></td>-->
             <!-- Delete function = clear & hide input row -->
           </tr>
           <tr id="row1">
             <td id="date_row1">24.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row1">Credit Card</td>
             <td id="category_row1">Expense: Restaurants</td>
             <td id="amount_row1">- $32.45</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('1')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
             </td>
           </tr>
           <tr id="row2">
             <td id="date_row2">24.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row2">Cash</td>
             <td id="category_row2">Transfer: Credit Card</td>
             <td id="amount_row2">+ $250.00</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('2')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button2" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('2')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
             </td>
           </tr>
              <tr id="row3">
             <td id="date_row3">24.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row3">Credit Card</td>
             <td id="category_row3">Transfer: Cash</td>
             <td id="amount_row3">- $250.00</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('3')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('3')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
             </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
       </div>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";

 var date=document.getElementById("date_row"+no);
 var account=document.getElementById("account_row"+no);
 var category=document.getElementById("category_row"+no);
 var amount=document.getElementById("amount_row"+no);

 var date_data=date.innerHTML;
 var account_data=account.innerHTML;
 var category_data=category.innerHTML;
 var amount_data=amount.innerHTML;

 date.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='date_text"+no+"' value='"+date_data+"'>";    //Should input type here be date?
 account.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='account_text"+no+"' value='"+account_data+"'>";
 category.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='category_text"+no+"' value='"+category_data+"'>";
 amount.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='amount_text"+no+"' value='"+amount_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var date_val=document.getElementById("date_text"+no).value;
 var account_val=document.getElementById("account_text"+no).value;
 var category_val=document.getElementById("category_text"+no).value;
 var amount_val=document.getElementById("amount_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("date_row"+no).innerHTML=date_val;
 document.getElementById("account_row"+no).innerHTML=account_val;
 document.getElementById("category_row"+no).innerHTML=category_val;
 document.getElementById("amount_row"+no).innerHTML=amount_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}

function add_row()
{
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_date").value;
 var new_country=document.getElementById("new_account").value;
 var new_age=document.getElementById("new_category").value;
 var new_age=document.getElementById("new_amount").value;

 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='date_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_date+"</td><td id='account_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_account+"</td><td id='category_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_category+"</td><td id='amount_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_amount+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_date").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_account").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_category").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_amount").value="";
}
```

FULL HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Net Worth</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="title">
     <h1 class=accounts>Accounts</h1><br><button type=button class="edit" id="edit"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="Accounts">
      <br><br><button type="button" class="collapsible"><h3 id="Accounts">&nbsp;Fiat Accounts</h3></button>
       <div class="content">
         <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Cash</h4><h4 id="balance">$5322.54</h4></div>
         <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Credit Card</h4><h4 id="balance">$1362.21</h4></div>
         <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Checking Account</h4><h4 id="balance">$4322.50</h4></div>
         <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Savings Account</h4><h4 id="balance">$12322.50</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Stocks & Commodeties">
      <br><button type="button" class="collapsible"><h3>&nbsp;Stocks & Commodeties</h3></button>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">AAPL</h4><h4 id="balance">$12322.54</h4></div>
        <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">DJ 50 Titans ETF</h4><h4 id="balance">$24322.21</h4></div>
        <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Physical Gold</h4><h4 id="balance">$1822.50</h4></div>
        <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Oil Certificates</h4><h4 id="balance">$5322.50</h4></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Digital Currencies">
      <br><button type="button" class="collapsible"><h3>&nbsp;Digital Currencies</h3></button>
      <div class="content">
       <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Bitcoin</h4><h4 id="balance">$2322.54</h4></div>
       <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Ethereum</h4><h4 id="balance">$4322.21</h4></div>
       <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Chainlink</h4><h4 id="balance">$1322.50</h4></div>
       <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">0xBTC</h4><h4 id="balance">$322.54</h4></div>
       <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">Uniswap</h4><h4 id="balance">$2322.21</h4></div>
       <div class="row"><h4 id="acc">AAVE</h4><h4 id="balance">$822.50</h4></div>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="two" id="two"><h2>$ 180,327.45</h2></div>
    <div class="three">
     <h1>Allocation</h1>
     <div class="Allocation"><canvas id="myChart" width="50" height="50"></canvas></div>
    </div>
    <div class="four">
     <h1>Net Worth</h1>
     <div class="networth"><canvas id="myChart2" width="50" height="18"></canvas></div>
    </div>
    <div class="five">
     <h1>Transactions</h1>
     <div class="txlist"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="1500" >
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div class="scroll" style="width:320px; height:80px; overflow:auto;">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" border="0" width="1500" id="data_table">
           <tr id="addtx">
             <td><input type="date" id="new_date" placeholder="Date"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_account" placeholder="Account"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_category" placeholder="Category"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
             <td><input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="add_row();">
             <!--<input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('')"></td>-->
             <!-- Delete function = clear & hide input row -->
           </tr>
           <tr id="row1">
             <td id="date_row1">24.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row1">Credit Card</td>
             <td id="category_row1">Expense: Restaurants</td>
             <td id="amount_row1">- $32.45</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('1')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
             </td>
           </tr>
           <tr id="row2">
             <td id="date_row2">24.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row2">Cash</td>
             <td id="category_row2">Transfer: Credit Card</td>
             <td id="amount_row2">+ $250.00</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('2')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button2" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('2')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
             </td>
           </tr>
              <tr id="row3">
             <td id="date_row3">24.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row3">Credit Card</td>
             <td id="category_row3">Transfer: Cash</td>
             <td id="amount_row3">- $250.00</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('3')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('3')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
             </td>
           </tr>
              <tr id="row4">
             <td id="date_row4">24.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row4">Credit Card</td>
             <td id="category_row4">Expense: Clothing</td>
             <td id="amount_row4">- $84.95</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button4" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('4')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button4" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('4')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('4')">
             </td>
           </tr>
              <tr id="row5">
             <td id="date_row5">23.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row5">Cash</td>
             <td id="category_row5">Expense: Groceries</td>
             <td id="amount_row5">- $25.23</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button5" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('5')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button5" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('5')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('5')">
             </td>
           </tr>
              <tr  id="row6">
             <td id="date_row6">23.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row6">Credit Card</td>
             <td id="category_row6">Income: Salary</td>
             <td id="amount_row6">+ $2500.00</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button6" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('6')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button6" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('6')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('6')">
             </td>
           </tr>
              <tr  id="row7">
             <td id="date_row7">23.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row7">Checking Account</td>
             <td id="category_row7">Transfer: Savings Account</td>
             <td id="amount_row7">- $500.00</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button7" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('7')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button7" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('7')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('7')">
             </td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="row8">
             <td id="date_row8">22.08.2020</td>
             <td id="account_row8">Savings Account</td>
             <td id="category_row8">Transfer: Checking Account</td>
             <td id="amount_row8">+ $500.00</td>
             <td>
               <input type="button" id="edit_button8" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('8')">
               <input type="button" id="save_button8" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('8')">
               <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('8')">
             </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
       </div>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
    <div class="six">
     <img src="refresh.svg" alt="Refresh" />
     <img src="sun.svg" alt="Light Mode" />
     <img src="settings.svg" alt="Settings" />
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./table.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./collapsible.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./edit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./chart2.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: @enhzflep I have no idea how to use a debugger, sorry. Would that be in my code editor (atom), or do you have a recommendation for a debugger?

Comment: your browser has one! It's a part of the Developer Tools. If using Chrome the hotkey is (Ctrl+Shift+I) Another way to access the goodies is right-click the page and select "Inspect". All browsers that I can think of have a debugger.

Comment: Okay, got you. I think its this: https://imgur.com/a/I9ON0vz

Comment: Looks like it. Well done. I'd comment out lines 11 and 12 of the code you've labelled as FULL HTML, then if this is successful, I'd research the implications of removing it from the file.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you so much, I'll be sure to do some more reading.

Comment: you should add this as an answer which you then accept so that the site removes the question from the 'unanswered list'. You'll receive the reputation bonus for an answer accepted as correct too. ;) I think there's even a badge for answering your own question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd comment out lines 11 and 12 of the code you've labelled as FULL HTML, then if this is successful, I'd research the implications of removing it from the file. – enhzflep